# Real time command prompt export in text field using pyqt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.3

What I am trying to achieve seems like it should be simple, but I can not find anything online to help.

I would like to take my pyqt program and, instead of using the command prompt, export all my print() commands to a qtextbrowser.

There are 2 parts to my question.

1. How do I disable the command prompt from showing up when the app is run.
2. How to output the print() commands to the text browser in real time.

I am using Python 3.3 and qt designer with pyqt4.

Thank you in advance!
Some of the code is confidential so if it is needed to help I can remove the sensitive info and post it.

Comment: I found out that I am able to hide the console window by changing the extension to .pyw and compiling it with windows= instead of console=. Now I still need a way to capture all the print() outputs and write them to my qtextBrowser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution. I was trying to do everything in my GUI thread. Im new to python but I am sure with some research I can teach myself threads.